# AWS SFTP Gateway API test works but SFTP clients return authentication failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am settings up a AWS SFTP using Cognito as the identify provider. I have a working Gateway API and can run tests on that successfully.

When I come to connect to the SFTP instance the username and password are rejected. I've checked the log files and there are not entries indicating that any calls to the Gateway API were made at all. This to me suggests something wrong with the IAM role associated with the SFTP instance and therefore the Gateway API is not being called. From my reading the configuration appears to be correct.

I'm working from the following blog page.
https://agilevision.io/blog/aws/2019/02/06/integrate-aws-sftp-with-custom-identity-provider.html

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong.

Comment: break down the problem in manageable parts to debug this.  Is your API gateway correctly working.  Try to invoke the lambda function first.  Does it work ?  Any thing in the logs ? Then try to invoke the API Gateway to check if that part works.  Then you will check on the SFTP side.

Comment: Hello Sebastian, I've checked the API gateway with the tools and it and the lambda functions appear to work correctly and return the expected results. The log files from the tests all show the operations taking place. However when you try to connect with an sftp client no new log messages ever appear, my initial thought is that the role to make the call to the gateway is never being run.

Comment: this is good debugging.  Did you try to follow the steps at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/authenticating-users.html ?  The doc provides a cloudformation template that setup all the infrastructure for you.  I would try that one and then - if it works - analyse the  difference between that setup and yours. It might be a role issue indeed, the AWS SFTP service must be authorized to call your API Gateway. Listing the role you assigned to your SFTP server in the question will make it easier to help :-)